# Passing a param containing a path to a controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes, parameter-passing, laravel-routing

I'm trying to pass a variable who contains a path from a form to a controller function in Laravel 4, with the purpose of download an image. I tried a lot of things but nothing worked for me. If I don't pass the parameter in the route, I get a missing parameter error, and if I pass the parameter in the route, I get a NotFoundHttpException.

Here's my code:

View Form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('download', $myPath))) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Download', array('class' => 'generator')); }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/download/{myPath}', array('uses' => 'ImagesController@download', 'as' => 'download'));
```

ImagesController function:

```
public function download($myPath){
    return Response::download($myPath);
}
```

When I click the submit I'm obtaining a URL like this with NotFoundHttpException:

> http://localhost/resizer/public/download/images/myimage.jpg

I don't understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually posting two variables. Try this instead

```
Route::post('/download/{myFolder}/{myFile}', array('uses' => 'ImagesController@download', 'as' => 'download'));
```

and in your controller

```
 public function download($myFolder, $myFile){
        return Response::download($myFolder.'/'.$myFile);
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks :) So, I can't pass a variable containing a "/" in the route, right?

Comment: Yes - correct - because it is triggering it as another variable when the URL is posted and evaluated. You can post variables with `/` in the normal $_POST data itself though.